# Java - How to search a string for 6 random numbers

Tags: java, string, indexof, digits

I have a (large) string file in my application  which contains a series of random character [a-Z] and [0-9] but also ";","/", "?", ":" and "@". I would like my application to tell me the nearest position where 6 digits are displayed consecutively ( like "105487" or "558463").

What would be the best way to achieve this?
Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: Please clarify on "nearest position". Is it the first occurance in the file?

Comment: Does the position mean line number and column in the file?

Comment: yes, i meant the first occurance. The position just means the number that the indexOf function in java would give as a number.

Comment: You can find what you are looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938498/get-the-index-of-a-pattern-in-a-string-using-regex

Comment: Are you looking for a sequence of *speicific* digits or just a sequence of *any* digits?

Comment: I am looking for a sequence of any digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *effective* approach would be to iterate the characters of the string and test if each is a digit. Upon finding a match continue to look for the rest of the sequence. Something like

```
int nDigits=0, i = 0;
CharacterIterator it = new StringCharacterIterator("very long string123456");
for (char ch=it.first(); ch != CharacterIterator.DONE; ch=it.next()) {
  i++;
  nDigits = (ch.isDigit() ? nDigits++ : 0);
  if (nDigits == 5) {
      // DONE. Position is "i"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely try this.

Answer (score 4):

You could use regex.

```
String regex = "(\\d{6})";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(YOU STRING HERE);
// Check all occurrences
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
    System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end());
    System.out.println(" Found: " + matcher.group());
}
```

This would do the job.

(Code sample from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8938549/975959))

Comment: for very large string it likely will fail with OOME

Comment: why not use REGEX \\d{6} instead?

Comment: Well, I don't know how long is string is, but I think it's a good option. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: @gtgaxiola, good question. I didn't remember it.. Edited. thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I will also try this approach, but I think that the answer that Johan Sjöberg posted would be best suited for my application.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Character.isDigit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) while iterating the string's characters and then count a number up until you have found 6 consecutive numbers or reset it if the sequence breaks. Keep track of the index and you can simply calculate the nearest position by subtraction.

This is not very efficient, but I think *O(n)* is sufficient if the strings are not too large. For optimization take a look on what *Luiggi Mendoza* has suggested in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought this would be the only solution, but i was hoping that java had a more efficient way of doing this. I will look into this.

Comment: @user1637234 you could use a regular expression like Lablabla has posted.

Comment: You can optimize this: if you find a digit in position X, then check the character in position X + 5, if that character is not a a digit, then start searching from here. If it's a digit, then go back (X+4, X+3...) until you find a non-digit and start again from the least position.

Comment: @gtgaxiola yeah, one of my String matching favorite algorithms when I can't rely on RegEx.