# Getting java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException while parsing content between RSS tags

Tags: java, parsing

I have a piece of content which has both html and rss, I would like to separate them and store in individual strings. So, I am trying to parse them based on their start and close tags and grab content between  rss   /rss .

Code works fine for html  & /html. However I am seeing errors for rss &  /rss.

Below is my code snippet.

```
// parse the responseStr to html
html = responseStr.substring(responseStr.indexOf("<html>"),
responseStr.lastIndexOf("</html>") + 7);
System.out.println("html string"+html );
```

Can someone please guide me what is wrong with the below code?

```
// parse the responseStr to rss
rss = responseStr.substring(responseStr.indexOf("<rss version="2.0">"),
responseStr.lastIndexOf("</rss>") + 6);
System.out.println("rss string = "+rss );
```

I get the below exception:

```
  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1093)
```

Comment: What do you mean by *I am seeing errors* - Also, can you post the text you're trying to parse?

Comment: why not use a library? an xml parser at the very least would allow you to use xpath

Comment: What errors do you see? Add them in the question please

Comment: The above code works for me if your input string is `<rss> ... </rss>`. Please post your input string.

Comment: chances are `responseStr.lastIndexOf("</rss>") + 6` doesn't exist

Comment: I have posted the exception above. The rss content(input string) I am trying to parse is very huge and it is in the rss standard format and coming as a string next to html content

Comment: Just to take a stab in the dark, does the input start with `<rss>`?  Or does the rss tag, perhaps, have attributes, say something like: `<rss version="2.0">`.

Comment: The input has content starting with <html> and </html> followed by <rss> and ends with </rss>. So, I am trying to parse out this content to get content between and including <rss> and </rss>

Comment: Check if your text starts with `<rss` and ends with `</rss>` some tags end with `/>`. Also some tags in HTML does not have end tags. check the case as well Better to use some HTML/RSS parsers IMHO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely that your call to `substring` is being passed invalid indexes for your `responseStr`. You need to verify that your string actually contains the `<rss>` and `</rss>` tags before you call substring.

Try this:

```
String result;
int start = responseStr.indexOf("<rss>");
int end = responseStr.lastIndexOf("</rss>");

if (start != -1 && end != -1)
{
  result = "rss string = " + responseStr.substring(start, end + 6);
}
else
{
  result = "rss string not found";
}

System.out.println(result);
```

From the [JavaDocs for `String.indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29), we know that if the string does not occur, `-1` will be returned.

Comment: I do have rss string, however, when I use your code it prints rss string not found.

Comment: @smiley If "rss string not found" is being printed, then one or both of the rss tags are missing. You need to inspect your string. You can also alter the above code to tell you which of the tags (opening or closing) is missing specifically.

Comment: ah.. I just noticed I am getting rss tag as <rss version="2.0"> and not as <rss> as someone mentioned above. How do I specify it in the code? I think I might need escape characters since I am not able to use  version="2.0" directly.

Comment: @smiley Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8938549/2479481) and use the pattern `"<rss [^>]*>"`

Comment: Thank you very much Luke! I  tried this, I know its pretty crude -- responseStr.indexOf("<rss version=") this worked for me though :) Thanks for all your help!

Comment: If you're going to just use `indexOf`, I would recommend using `"<rss"` as your search string, rather than `"<rss version="`.

Comment: I also have   <rssfeed>  </rssfeed> tag before <rss version="2.0">. Thats why when I tried "<rss" it picks up the 1st entry <rssfeed> I do not want to keep this

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be easier by using

`StringUtils.substringsBetween(String str,String open,String close)`

[javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringBetween%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

[apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)

Example:

```
String[] rss= StringUtils.substringsBetween(testHtml, "<rss>", "</rss>");
    for (String s : rss) {
        System.out.println("td rss:" + rss); 
}

public static String substringBetween(String str, String open, String close) {
    if (str == null || open == null || close == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int start = str.indexOf(open);
    if (start != INDEX_NOT_FOUND) {
        int end = str.indexOf(close, start + open.length());
        if (end != INDEX_NOT_FOUND) {
            return str.substring(start + open.length(), end);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend xml parser though instead of below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String responseStr = "<rss ...>------content-----</rss>";
    int start = responseStr.indexOf("<rss");
    String content = null;
    if (start != -1) {
        start = responseStr.indexOf(">", start);
        if (start != -1) {
            int end = responseStr.lastIndexOf("</rss>");
            if (end != -1) {
                content = responseStr.substring(start + 1, end);
            }
        }
    }
    if (content != null)
        System.out.println(content);
    else
        System.err.println("Content not found");

}
```

Output

```
------content-----
```