# Finding multiple hits with indexOf

Tags: java, indexof

I want to find multiple hits with the indexOf method.

I have got this line to search in:

```
public static final String DNA = "ATGTTGCTGGCATAGATGTTAACTTCCAC";
```

For example i would like to search the locations of AC in this String. I want to do that with this method. At the moment i only get 21 a couple of times. As i should get 21 and 27 ones.

```
public int[] zoek(String gezocht)
{
    // goed = 21+27 bij AC
    int fromIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < DNA.length(); i++)
    {
       fromIndex = DNA.indexOf(gezocht, fromIndex);
       dna.add(fromIndex);

    }
    System.out.println(dna);
    return zoek;
}
```

Comment: Why is that string final. String is already made immutable.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma That makes it a constant (you can't replace the reference in the variable with a reference to a different immutable `String`).

Comment: Use regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938498/get-the-index-of-a-pattern-in-a-string-using-regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test001
{
    public static final String DNA = "ATGTTGCTGGCATAGATGTTAACTTCCAC";

    public static Integer[] zoek(String gezocht)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> dna = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < DNA.length())
        {
           int fromIndex = DNA.indexOf(gezocht, i);
           if (fromIndex >= 0){
               dna.add(fromIndex);
               i = fromIndex + 1;
           }else{
               break;
           }
        }
        System.out.println(dna);
        Integer[] zoek = new Integer[dna.size()]; 
        return dna.toArray(zoek);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Integer[] ind = zoek("AC");
        for (int fromIndex : ind){
            System.out.println(fromIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

I would name the variables differently btw.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test001
{
    public static final String DNA = "ATGTTGCTGGCATAGATGTTAACTTCCAC";

    public static Integer[] search(String sought)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> hits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int startIndex = 0;
        while (startIndex < DNA.length())
        {
           int foundIndex = DNA.indexOf(sought, startIndex);
           if (foundIndex >= 0){
               hits.add(foundIndex);
               startIndex = foundIndex + 1;
           }else{
               break;
           }
        }
        System.out.println(hits);
        Integer[] found = new Integer[hits.size()]; 
        return hits.toArray(found);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Integer[] found = search("AC");
        for (int foundIndex : found){
            System.out.println(foundIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a while-loop instead, something like:

```
int fromIndex = 0;
while((fromIndex = dna.indexOf(gezocht, fromIndex)) != -1) {
    ...
    fromIndex++; // We don't want to find the previous match again
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one to `fromIndex` so that `indexOf` won't just find the same occurrence again. You should also not loop as many times as the string has characters, but as long as occurrences are found:

```
int fromIndex = -1;
while ((fromIndex = DNA.indexOf(gezocht, fromIndex + 1)) != -1) {
   dna.add(fromIndex);
}
```