# How to get the position of a substring in a string in Java without using any built in methods.

Tags: java, regex

Most answers have length() or charAt() or toCharArray() methods used. However I want to do get the position of a substring in a string without using any of these. 
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Why would you want to not use those methods? Work easier, not harder.

Comment: Maybe you should be a bit more specific on what you are actually trying do. Maybe regex is a possibility.

Comment: Would [indexOf()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm) help?

Comment: You can use Pattern Matcher: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938498/get-the-index-of-a-pattern-in-a-string-using-regex

Comment: If you do not want to use any inbuilt string methods , pattern matching may be your only option.

Comment: @TylerWeaver My guess would be that it's a homework assignment, and not using those methods are part of the requirements.

Comment: @DennisMeng I think it's impossible to achieve what he is asking. Unless he means not using any of the built-in string functions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming that too (no built-in string methods, not no built-in methods)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
 public class HelloWorld {

     public static void main(String []args) {
        char[] string = {'t', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 0};
        char[] substring = {'i', 's', ' ', 0};
        int c = 0;
        Boolean found = false;
        int position = 0;

        while (string[c] != '\0') {
            int f = 0;
            while (string[c+f]==substring[f]) f++;
                if (substring[f]=='\0') {
                    found = true;
                    position = c;
                }
            c++;
        }
        if (found)
            System.out.println("found at position " + position);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I suppose *not using Java* is one way to avoid using Java's built-in methods, but what language *is* that? ;)

Comment: pfft. so i wrote from memory.. only non-java is assigning string to char[]. change assignment to {'t','h','i','s',' ','i','s',' ','a',' ','s','t','r','i','n','g'} and the other string in a similar way, and it will run. Assignments are confused with C

Comment: add a string terminator too  ie. {'t','h','i','s',' ','i','s',' ','a',' ','s','t','r','i','n','g',0}

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much.  I was poking at you for trying to answer the question in the first place.  I suspect it's from a certification exam or something, because I've seen it a few times before (here at SO or elsewhere), and they never say why they're asking.  I didn't downvote you though; I saved that for the question itself.

Comment: i don't care about downvotes, but there are always ways to think outside the box. Telling folk it can't be done and shouldn't be done is not helpful. In testing there are many reasons to write code that don't follow rules and practises.. my answer has a couple of bugs, but it shows you can do anything if you think about it hard enough. I don't suggest using C style coding in Java, but knowing how should not be frowned on :)

Comment: Thanks code Charlie I ran when I run the code I get the following error.

Comment: Thanks for the code Charlie, i am getting the following error when i run the program. Can you please suggest

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at StringProblem.getSubsStringPos(StringProblem.java:14)
 at StringProblem.main(StringProblem.java:31)

Comment: ive edited it so it will compile and run.. string to char[] is the only conversion to do exactly what you want. As it is i hope it gives you ideas about character manipulations. The code is compiled and running here: http://www.browxy.com/SavedCode/22195

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible. A `String` is backed by a `char[]`. The only way to access that `char[]` or its elements is through `String` methods. If you can't use any of those methods, you cannot find a substring within it.