# Problems with Regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to remove the first occurrence of a pattern from a string in Java.

Source string: `DUMMY01012016DUMMY01012016`

Format is 1-8 alpha-numeric characters followed by a date `MMddyyyy` followed by any number of alpha-numerics.

Want I'm trying to achieve is remove all beginning chars including the first date occurrence. So in the example below I would be left with `DUMMY01012016`.

Here is a simplified version of what I have tried: `".*\\d{4}(2016|2017|2015)"`

That works well until the pattern is matched more than once. So in the example `matcher.replaceFirst("")` will replace the entire source string and not just the first occurrence.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks. Stephan

Comment: How is `.\d{4}(2016|2017|2015).?` matching your pattern ? It's not according to your format of _1-8 alpha-numeric characters followed by a date MMddyyyy followed by any number of alpha-numerics._ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the index of a pattern in a string using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938498/get-the-index-of-a-pattern-in-a-string-using-regex)

Comment: By "alpha-numeric characters" do you actually mean *alphabetic* characters, i.e. letters?  "Alphanumeric" includes digits.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the `*` quantifier is greedy.  It will cause the preceding sub-pattern to match as many times as possible without causing the overall match to fail (if a match is possible at all).  Thus the tail of your pattern `.*\d{4}(2016|2017|2015)` will match the last occurrence of a date in the string, whereas you want it to match the first.

You can solve this problem by switching to a "reluctant" quantifier instead:

```
myString.replaceFirst(".*?\d{4}(2016|2017|2015)", "");
```

There, `*?` is a reluctant quantifier: it matches zero or more instances of the preceding sub-pattern, as *few* as possible to enable an overall match (if an overall match is possible).

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work:

```
(\w{1,8}?\d{8})(?:\1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is that the `.*` is *greedy*. It means that it matches as much as it can at first. Then the regexp engine starts to step back symbol by symbol until a full match had been found.

So, roughly:

Step 1) `.*` macthes the whole `DUMMY01012016DUMMY01012016`

Step 2) The engine steps back symbol by symbol trying to match the remaining part:
`DUMMY01012016DUMMY0101201` -> `DUMMY01012016DUMMY010120` -> `DUMMY01012016DUMMY01012` -> .. -> `DUMMY01012016DUMMY`

Step 3) A complete match is found -> `DUMMY01012016DUMMY01012016`

You can try something like this:

```
@Test
public void testReplace()
{
    String string = "DUMMY01012016DUMMY01012016";

    String replaced = string.replaceFirst("\\w{1,8}\\d{4}(2016|2017|2015)", "");

    Assert.assertEquals("DUMMY01012016", replaced);
}
```

To understand the difference between lazy and greedy you can experiment and make the asterisk lazy by adding a question mark `?`., e.g. `.*?\d{4}(2016|2017|2015)`. Then the engine will do the opposite, it will match lazily at the beginning and step forward character by character.