# Is there a strpbrk equivalent in Java? and how to use it?

Tags: java, c, string

If the code is something like this

```
const char str1[] = "abcde2fghi3jk4l";
const char str2[] = "34";
char *ret;
ret = strpbrk(str1, str2);
```

how should I replicate the same in Java?

Comment: adding the expected result may help

Comment: @jhamon `ret` is a pointer to the first occurrence in str1 of any of the characters that are part of str2.

Comment: goggle `java find string in string`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938498/get-the-index-of-a-pattern-in-a-string-using-regex

Comment: Please add the expected results, right now your question requires someone to leave the site to figure out what `strpbrk()` does

Answer (score 2):

First off, Java is not C and it has no pointers the same way C has.

The closest I can think of to your code is something along the lines:

```
final String str1 = "abcde2fghi3jk4l";
final String str2 = "34";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str1, str2);
String ret = st.hasMoreTokens() ? str1.substring(st.nextToken().length()) : null;
```

This code uses [java.util.StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), shipped with the JRE.

You can try it yourself [here](https://ideone.com/lFYvCK).

Answer (score 2):

There is this function: 
`StringUtils.indexOfAny(String str, String searchChars)` which will return you the index of first matching character from `searchChars`. Hope this is what you were looking for.
This is quite an expensive approach, see if you can use a better one.

Dependency for which is `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3`

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent in java.

One possible solution would be the use of [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

```
java.util.regex.Pattern
java.util.regex.Matcher

var str1 = "abcde2fghi3jk4l";
var str2 = Pattern.quote("34");

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("["+str2+"]").matcher(str1);
if ( m.find() )
  return m.start();
return -1;
```

Comment: I used the example information given in the question, I trust the user will be able to divine the required character checking for a truly production solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct equivalent using standard API.

**First solution**: using [Apache StringUtils library: indexOfAny()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#indexOfAny-java.lang.CharSequence-char...-)

```
ret = StringUtils.indexOfAny(str2,str1.toCharArray());
```

**Second solution**: using standard Java 8 API, this is quite verbose

```
    String str1 = "abcde2fghi3jk4l";
    String str2 = "34";
    OptionalInt ret = str2.chars().map(c -> str1.indexOf(c)).min();
```

**Third solution**: using regex, but str1 should not contain any regex special chars so I would not recommend it ...

```
Matcher matcher = str2.matcher("["+str1+"]");
if(matcher.find()){
    ret = matcher.start();
}
```