# Why does this while loop not exit despite simple condition met? It keeps going back into the for loop

Tags: java, loops

Basically I am checking to see if the first x in a string is followed by another x.

When the index of the character array gets to the first x it should add 1 to 'count' and exit out of the while loop.

When I tried stepping into it, I see that despite 'firstX' being equal to 1 it goes back to the for loop and not the while loop. Then it even makes 'firstX' equal to 2.

```
String str = "axxbb";
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
int firstX = 0;
int secondX = 0;

while (firstX < 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length - 1; i++) {
        if (charArray[i] == 'x') {
            firstX = firstX + 1;
            // firstX becomes 1 here after detecting the first x in the string
            secondX = i + 1; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The while condition is only checked once per turn of the while-loop. The whole for-loop runs in that turn.

Answer (score 1):

The inner for loop would continue to execute until it finishes, then the while condition would be re-evaluated. You could `break` out of the for loop when your condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

Try using>>>

```
String str = "axxbb";
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
int firstX = 0;
int secondX = 0;

while (firstX < 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length - 1; i++) {
        if (charArray[i] == 'x') {
            firstX = firstX + 1;
            // firstX becomes 1 here after detecting the first x in the string
            secondX = i + 1; 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to exit on either of two different condition being met.  Try combining your loops.

```
String str = "axxbb";
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
int firstX = 0;
int secondX = 0;
int i = 0
while (firstX < 1 && i < charArray.length - 1) {
    if (charArray[i] == 'x') {
        firstX = firstX + 1;
        // firstX becomes 1 here after detecting the first x in the string
        secondX = i + 1; 
    }
    i++;
}
```

Note you'll still have an index out of bounds problem with

```
String str = "abbx";
```

Have you considered using a regex function?
[Get the index of a pattern in a string using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938498/get-the-index-of-a-pattern-in-a-string-using-regex)